# Looping out barcode divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

I am trying to loop through an array using barcode.js to then create a printable div. I need to have spacing in to make it a certain number per page (found under `req.user.perpage`)

**My JS function to get the IDs and the loop out the divs**

```
getSelected = function(){
  var array = [];
  $('.my_table tbody tr').each(function(index, object){
    if($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked"))
      array.push($(this).find('.id').attr("name"));
  });
  var test = 'barcode';
   // var test = document.getElementById("test123").innerHTML;
  var codeType = document.getElementById("codeType").innerHTML;
  console.log(test);
  console.log(codeType);
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
      var value = array[i];
      $('#target').append('<img id="barcode"/>')
      $('#barcode').JsBarcode(value, {format: codeType}, {width: 2, height: 90});
    console.log(array[i]);
  }


  // window.print();

};
```

I can get it to output only one barcode but not multiple. I have 2 check boxes on the page that work and give the ids I need them to. I can't seem to get them to all show up though.

**My HTML**

```
<div id="target">
   <!-- all divs will append here -->
</div>
```

Comment: In your for loop you are appending each time a div with the same "barcorediv" id. This will produce an invalid output since id are unique

Comment: That should not prevent any output. It might not be proper for long term use but to get something working then polish it up, it's fine fro now. I care more about making it work than anything. I will change the divs ids later to something better but until it works it is pointless to even bother.

Comment: @LelioFaieta I went back and changed a few small things. I can't figure out how to increment the div `ID` in the loop without it just failing out-right.

Comment: i'd concatenate a number to the id. Start with 1 and increment for each for iteration

Comment: @LelioFaieta What would that look like? I know the number part, I would like it to be barcode1 barcode2 barcode3 ect. I just don't know how to add that number onto them in JS during the loop.

Comment: what about something like: '<img id="barcode'+i+'"/>'? In this case I am using i that will start from 0 but this is just an hint for you

Comment: @LelioFaieta Okay I did have it sorta right in one of my tries. I just didn't have that last `+`